# How to group by IEnumerable property value

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have

```
class Class1 A {
    int Id;
    IEnumerable<Class2> B;
}

class Class2 B {
    string Title;
}
```

So if I have (in json format)

```
{Id: 0, B: [{"Title": "a"}, {"Title": "b"}, {"Title": "c"} ]}
```

I want to group by `Title` so the result would be

```
 { {"Id": 0, "Title": "a"}, {"Id": 0, "Title": "b"}, {"Id": 0, "Title": "c"} };
```

Prefer a solution with LINQ. Tried to do:

```
var result = A.GroupBy(x => x.B)
```

(I expected that this will not work) and

```
var result = A.SelectMany(x => x.B).GroupBy(x => x)
```

but then I have only titles. How I can do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not *grouping*, you're doing the opposite - *flattening* - which is done with `SelectMany`:

```
A.SelectMany(a => a.B, (a, b) => new {a.Id, b.Title});
```